# Copy ignore properties with tortoise svn?

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn

I can't find a good answer to the following problem.

We use windows machines and Tortoise svn to maintain our projects.
We create a repository and do a checkout.

In this checkout we copy our basic "php project" and commit it.

Let's assume we have some folders like:

assets/news/

assets/photoalbum/

All these folders should have an ignore pattern to ignore all files in it. Because we don't want to commit the files, because they shouldn't be updated to our production environment.

Is there a way to set a default ignore for every new repository or use a script to add the ignore on each folder in the assets folder?

I tried adding a svn:ignore on the root folder as "assets/*/*.*", but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set `svn:ignore` for just the files in that directory.

I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can work. It would allow you to prohibit adding certain files to the repository based upon their name using globbing patterns or regular expressions.

Add this into the control file:

```
[ FILE You can't add files into the assets directory ]
file = **/assets/**
access = read-only
users = @ALL
```

and no one will be able to add or modify any files that are under the assets directory. In many ways, it's better than svn:ignore which can be *ignored* itself. This is a complete and utter ban.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. The checkout is used in our local development. By testing images will be uploaded in this directory. But we don't want to commit these images since these test images are not needed when we checkout/update to our production environment. But it should be possible to add/edit files in the folder

Comment: Do you mean you don't want images commited to these directories, but other files are okay? You can modify the `file` parameter to set the access to something like `**/assets/**/*.gif` or use match and do `/assets/.*/\.(gif|jpg|img)$`. That will allow you to edit and even add other file types, but not images, gifs, jpgs, etc. You can also use `no-add` instead of `read-only`. This will allow you to edit file already there, but not add new ones. The `file` and `match` parameter can specify individual files and types not just directories.